# How to get a wb.sheetname and wb.name based on button location?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently my code is using the workbook name and worksheet within the code for referencing, but is there a way to assign them to a variable that is automatically updated based on the button location? I've assigned a button to a macro I'm using.

- For example; if i were to move the macro to another file, and put the button within the new workbook, is there a way to update the workbook name and worksheet name that its located in?

Or is there any other method to make the workbook and worksheet name variables that update based on the file its located in?

Comment: Perhaps consider using `ThisWorkbook` instead of referencing the workbook by name.

Comment: @BigBen mhm yeah that would work, Ii was hoping there would be a "Thisworkbook.Worksheet.Name" function lol

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name`?

Comment: i get the error "Compile Error: Type Mismatch" when I run "Set Reference = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name". Not sure why

Comment: `.Name` returns a `String`. If you want a sheet, then drop the `.Name`.

Comment: Is there a way to assign it to a variable then? Because Variable cant be set to "ThisWorkbook" alone

Comment: Sure a variable can be set to this workbook: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = ThisWorkbook`.